# .editorconfig ignored after migrating from old csproj to new Project SDK

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, csproj, csc

I have a solution with old style .csproj files. Target is .NET Framework 4.8.
I'm using MSBuild 17.2.1.25201.

I started using .editorconfig to configure severity of warning messages, for example:

```
[*.cs]
# XXX 3.1.0.153 depends on YYY (>= 3.1.0) but YYY 3.1.0 was not found. 
# An approximate best match of YYY 3.1.0.69 was resolved.
dotnet_diagnostic.NU1603.severity = none
```

It worked perfectly and the warning NU1603 is not showing again.

Afterwards, I migrated the projects to new Project SDK and now the settings from .editorconfig are not being respected anymore. For example, the warning NU1603 started showing again.

Is there something additional I should do or is this just some kind of problem with msbuild/compiler?

New *.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{XXXX...}</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyTitle>My.Module</AssemblyTitle>
    <Product>My.Module</Product>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I keep .editorconfig in the root solution directory, so the structure look like this:

```
.\
.\My.ModuleA
.\My.ModuleB
.\My.sln
.\.editorconfig
```

**Update**
I found that only this specific NU1603 cannot be ignored. The other warnings are ignored correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/42762) which looks pretty similar to what you're encountering.

But you have another option, as you can read in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2022#to-suppress-a-specific-warning-for-a-single-nuget-package): add the `NoWarn` element to your `csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{XXXX...}</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyTitle>My.Module</AssemblyTitle>
    <Product>My.Module</Product>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <NoWarn>NU1603</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And just for the sake of completeness: you can omit a couple of default elements within your `csproj`. Since I see a lot of default values, it probably can look similar to this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <NoWarn>NU1603</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I found that only warnings from NuGet are ignored. The other ignores work correctly! Maybe I will just add this specific NU1603 to NoWarn element.